# PHP / MySQL query stopped working for no apparent reason

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a page that alters a large quantity of variables in my MySQL database, and so far they've all worked great, but now all of the queries inside of a single logic-gate have stopped working for no apparent reason.

I've confirmed the following:
 - The variable posted and used in the "if" statement of the gate is as it was intended
 - The logic gate is triggered as intended (I can echo stuff and etc inside of it).
 - The database connection is established, I am successfully running queries of various types before and after this logic gate on the same connection variable.
 - The connection user has ALL PRIVILEDGES enabled, the aforementioned queries surrounding this logic gate are using similar functions successfully.

Here's the logic gate:

```
if (!empty($_POST["addqual"])){
    $coladqual = $_POST["addqual"];
    $sqlf = "ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE ('$coladqual') INT( 2 ) NOT NULL";
    $conn->query($sqlf);
    $sqlc = "INSERT INTO competencebonus (competence,bonus)
    VALUES ($coladqual,0)";
    $conn->query($sqlc);
}
```

I've tried multiple alterations, but they don't seem to execute no matter what I do. I've got at least 20 other queries in other logic gates before and after these two and there seems to be virtually no difference between them, apart from these two just not working at all.

EDIT - Here's the error (Thanks to all of you who provided me with the error report syntax)

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''TestAA') INT( 2 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE' at line 1*

What strikes me as odd is that only the closing parenthesis is around the post input (TestAA). Is it supposed to have both or neither?

I tried changing the syntax and got the following error:

Duplicate entry '0' for key 'TestAB'

The syntax was:

```
$sqlf = "ALTER TABLE users ADD `$coladqual` INT( 2 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE";
```

FINAL EDIT:

Made it work. Deleted the "NOT NULL" statement as recommended by Jeff Pucket II. Somehow this combined with the deletion of the parenthesis and use of backticks instead of apostrophe made the thing work.
Thanks for those of you who had the patience to help me with this.

Comment: Error checking should always come first. Self education is the most powerful.

Comment: You should check whether or not the query was executed successfully. If something fails, `$conn` will be able to report about it. (And you should specify whether you're using PDO or MySQLi.)

Comment: MySQLi.
How would I go about adding an error report to these queries?
All of the examples that I've found throughout the past year use an entirely different query format.

Comment: "for no apparent reason" is a reason to look more

Comment: Yeah yeah, I think we've established that I should have done an error report by now. I did admit in my post not knowing how to do that though, which made some post the code for doing it.
In general, this post would have been a lot better if I had refrained from posting it at the end of a super intense workday, I realize that now. Live and learn.

Comment: You're a sitting duck with that code for SQL Injection attacks as you're not using prepared statements and you've not even validated the user submitted data!

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that. I will be looking into SQL injection for my next project, but this one doesn't really need it as it's going to be hosted on a local server not accessible through the internet.
Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to alter an existing table with a unique not null column. I would expect this to fail if any rows already exist in the table, unless your engine imputes zero. Even then this would fail if there were more than one record because of the unique constraint. Also make sure that the column name being added doesn't already exist.

To get the error using MySQLi, try:
`$result = $conn->query($sqlf) or die($conn->error);`

Comment: I tried without NOT NULL, without UNIQUE, and without both. It doesn't work in any of the 3 variations.
Also, the far more "simple" INSERT INTO query isn't working either.

Comment: Alright, I'm back. Sorry, it was midnight in my timezone and I had been programming for 10 hours straight, my brain was deep fried!
Thanks for the error code, will try it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The 'unique' constraint should go at the end of your query

```
$sqlf = "ALTER TABLE users ADD ('$coladqual') INT( 2 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE";
```

Error checking depends on what flavor of MySQL you're running

Comment: Didn't work. I'm not sure what you mean by "flavor". I'm using a WAMP setup so I didn't spent too long looking into the software.

Comment: I was thinking mostly MySQLi vs MySQL. MySQL error reporting documentation is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Your syntax generally looks like your using MySQLi as in this documentation http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Is it possible you're running MySQLi functions on a MySQL db?

Comment: Try this way and see what you get

$add_col = mysql_query ( $sqlf, $conn );
    echo mysql_error($add_col);

Comment: My WAMP setup is only about half a year old so I find it unlikely that I am using a MySQL database. As far as I recall, non-i MySQL was deprecated long before that. Also, I am using MySQLi to connect to the database, that much is certain. I've been trying to steer clear of the deprecated functions as much as possible, but I really don't use that many functions as I tend to make roundabout solutions on the spot instead. In other words, I'm too much of a noob to know how to be "lazy" yet. :D

Comment: Fixed the problem, but wanted to thank you for your effort. I will remember to add the UNIQUE constraint at the end of my queries from now on.